# Download zip file from different server location in react js

Tags: reactjs

Folder structure on server:

-JAVA_PROJECT

---------DOWNLOAD_FOLDER

---------src

---------target

-REACT PROJECT

---------Public

---------src

---------node_modules

I have zip file in DOWNLOAD_FOLDER. Onclick of a button on react page i want to download the zip file.

My Code:

```
var urls = [
      "/files/ProductList.zip",   
    ];   
    var url = urls.pop();    
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.setAttribute("href", url);
    a.setAttribute("download", "");
    a.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    a.click();
```

I am able to download only the files placed in PUBLIC folder. Is there any wway to traverse location to DOWNLOAD_Folder and download the zip file?

Or shall i fetch zip file content using axios and download file?

Please suggest.

Comment: because you have relative path! you need absolute path! or your back-end need send to you path

Comment: I get url.html failed !